# Find pid of a process while its rinning on background

Tags: linux, unix, netstat

I have python sunning on my PC in a Linux machine .

```
ps -eaf | grep python
```

But now i dont know the process name say . Python is running on the port 7777. I only know the port no on which python with the bellow command .

```
netstat
```

Now i want to find out the pid no of python which is running on port 7777.
as i dont know the process name i only know port no 7777 . are there any command for the same problem .

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask. Also see [Where do I post questions about Dev Ops?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/134306)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use following :

```
lsof -i :7777
```

I will show you pid without knowing the process name , but knowing the port no

Comment: Ok this one helps

Answer (score 0):

```
sudo netstat -tunlp | grep :7777
```

You can use either `netstat` (deprecated) or `ss`, with the same options which are mnemonic:

```
-t = TCP
-u = UDP
-n = numeric output
-l = listening ports
-p = pid
```

Another commands that works, apart, from **lsof**, is **fuser** (the Linux one because the BSD's is different).

```
sudo fuser -n tcp -n 7777
```